# Uploading image from Swift app to PHP Side server

Tags: swift

I am currently making an app in Swift with very little experience in PHP. I have created a side server using online tutorials and here is the code for that:

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP Upload Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
        <input type ="hidden" name="partyGroupId" id="partyGroupId" value="10050"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click to Upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php //ignore this comment >
$uploadFolder = "./upload";
if (!file_exists($uploadFolder)) {
    mkdir($uploadFolder);
}

 $uploadFile = $uploadFolder . "/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]
 ["name"]);

if(!(getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]) !== false)) {
    echo "Sorry, your image is invalid";
    exit;
}

$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($uploadFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if($imageFileType != "jpg"
        && $imageFileType != "png"
        && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    exit;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    exit;
}

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
$uploadFile)) {
    echo "Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Swift 3.0 code:

```
func UploadRequest()
    {
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

let boundary = generateBoundaryString()


request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", 
forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

if (notesImage.image == nil)
{
    return
}

let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(notesImage.image!)


if(image_data == nil)
{
    return
}


let body = NSMutableData()

let fname = "test.png"
let mimetype = "image/png"


body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"test\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("hi\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)



body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
body.append(image_data!)
body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)


request.httpBody = body as Data



let session = URLSession.shared


let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
    (
    data, response, error) in

    guard ((data) != nil), let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    {
        print(dataString)
    }

})

task.resume()


}


func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
}

}
```

When I run the iOS app, it always gives the message: Sorry your image is invalid. I have tried different images and it is not working. What do I do?

Comment: First, your index.php is probably index.html. Then: did you try the html page to upload the same image successfully (to make sure it does not have to do with php-configuration like file size)?

Answer (score 0):

Your php expects the image as "fileToUpload", but in Swift you use the name "file", so the php code will not get the expected image.